# Inserting values into a sorted array

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, insert

What would be the quickest way to insert values into the correct position in a sorted numpy array?

For example, I would like to insert every value of `b`into `a`:

```
a = [1,1,2,4,7,7,11,13,13,13,15,20,25,26,27,30,45,70]

b = [5,7,9,45]
```

I've tried looping through `a` for each value of `b` and inserting it that way. I've also tried the `bisect_left` method:

```
for i in b:
a.insert(bisect_left(a,i),i)
```

Both methods are too slow as I have hundreds of thousands of data elements to go through.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using a more efficient data structure like a binary search tree will certainly make things go a bit faster. `O(log n)` inserts instead of of `O(n)`

Comment: If `b` is already sorted then you can use the **merge** part of merge sort: [Algorithm to merge sorted arrays](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays)

Answer (score 13):

You could use `searchsorted` and `insert`:

```
a = numpy.array([1,1,2,4,7,7,11,13,13,13,15,20,25,26,27,30,45,70])
b = numpy.array([5,7,9,45])
ii = numpy.searchsorted(a, b)
a = numpy.insert(a, ii, b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use builtin `sort` method. It implements `timsort`. If the list is almost sorted, it will be very fast.

```
a.extend(b)
a.sort()
```

Comment: You solution O(NlogN), but possible made O(N).

Answer (score 4):

let's note `n = len(a) and m = len(b)`,

1. you can use a binary search to find each element's position and insert it,
   that would done in **m*n*log(n)** time
2. you can merge both arrays, that would have an n+m complexity
3. you can use a specialized structure, a balanced binary tree, you can find a lot of implementation of these in python, the time complexity will be **mlog(n)**

Now given possible values of n and m, you can determine which solution is best, but don't expect to do better than that

Comment: I agree with BST, using structure here will simplify and speed up the insertions

Answer (score 2):

For a more pythonic approach, You can use `bisect.insort(your_list, your_value)` to insert a value into the correct position of a sorted list. Like this:

```
import bisect

a = [1,1,2,4,7,7,11,13,13,13,15,20,25,26,27,30,45,70]
b = [5,7,9,45]

for value in b:
    bisect.insort(a, value)

# Now a == [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 13, 13, 13, 15, 20, 25, 26, 27, 30, 45, 45, 70]
```

Answer (score -3):

You solution slow becaue you have a lot of inserts. Each insrt is O(N) complexity.

My solution:
a = [1,1,2,4,7,7,11,13,13,13,15,20,25,26,27,30,45,70]
b = [5,7,9,45]

insert b.Length items into end of a.
a = [1,1,2,4,7,7,11,13,13,13,15,20,25,26,27,30,45,70,x,x,x,x]
b = [5,7,9,45]

Take 3 pointers:

1. Pointer into **a** to last actual element(in example pointer to **70**)
2. Pointer into **b** to last element(in example pointer to **45**)
3. POinter to last of `a`

**Here my solution in C#:**

```
    int p1 = a.Length - 1;
    int p2 = b.Length - 1;
    int p3 = a.Length + b.Length - 1;

    //Insert b.Length items to end of a.

    while (p3 >= 0 && p2 >= 0)
    {
        if (p1 < 0 || b[p2] >= a[p1])
        {
            a[p3--] = b[p2--];
        }
        else
        {
            a[p3--] = a[p1--];
        }
    }
```

Comment: If each insert is O(N), then its O(N^2)

Comment: My solution without insets, Only 1 bulk insert into start to reserve place into array.

Comment: This is a Python question.